# Pass parameters through angularjs 2 to restful services

Tags: web-services, angular, spring-rest

I am trying to call a webservice which is as follows,

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/persons" },method = RequestMethod.GET,headers="Accept=application/json")
public List<Person> getDummyData(@RequestParam(value="search", defaultValue="a") String search,HttpServletRequest req){
    List<Person> listOfMatchedPersons=listOfPersons.stream().filter(person->person.getName().contains(search)).collect(Collectors.toList());

    req.getParameterMap().forEach((k,v)->System.out.println(k+" : "+v));

    return listOfMatchedPersons;
}
```

I want to call this service with some parameter from my UI, but it always executes this method with default value of search i.e. a.
Following is my angularjs 2's service that is consuming this service,

```
search(term: string) {

    var params = new URLSearchParams();
    params.set('search', term);

    let aopsServices = 'http://localhost:8080/dummy/persons';//?search='+term;
    this.ot = this.http
        .get(aopsServices,params)
        .map(response => response.json())
    ;

    return this.ot;
}
```

however if i change the url to `http://localhost:8080/dummy/persons'?search='+term;` it works.

And also what should be the ideal approach to access the restful services if they are secured ?

Comment: The `get` method doesn't receive an `URLSearchParams` object, it receives a `RequestOptionsArgs` object, which has a `search` property of type `URLSearchParams`. See: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/Http-class.html , https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/RequestOptionsArgs-interface.html and https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/URLSearchParams-class.html

Comment: Thanks @Langley , I corrected the parameter

Comment: np, is it working now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two ways to do that:

- Leveraging the `URLSearchParams` class:

  ```
  search(term: string) {
    var params = new URLSearchParams();
    params.set('search', term);

    let aopsServices = 'http://localhost:8080/dummy/persons';
    this.ot = this.http
               .get(aopsServices, { search: params })
               .map(response => response.json());

    return this.ot;
  }
  ```
- Use of ` (backticks) instead of single quotes '

  ```
  search(term: string) {
    let aopsServices = `http://localhost:8080/dummy/persons?search=${term}`;
    this.ot = this.http
                .get(aopsServices, { search: params })
                .map(response => response.json());

    return this.ot;
  }
  ```

  The second approach is more concise but doesn't urlencode the parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I changed my code to

```
   var params = new URLSearchParams();
    params.set('search', term);

    let aopsServices = 'http://localhost:8080/dummy/persons';
    this.ot = this.http
        .get(aopsServices,new RequestOptions({search:params}))
        .map(response => response.json());
```

and it worked.
I misread the documentation of get.